# SCCM 2007: Create new Advertisement using WMI

Tags: wmi, sccm, sccm-2007

I'm trying to create a new advertisement using Powershell.  I've looked around and found a bunch of scripts that use WMI.  Using Set-WMIInstance upon the **SMS_Advertisement** class.   I can accomplish this!

My issue is that it seems there is another class **SMS_AdvertisementInfo**.  When I use the SCCM 2007 Console and create a new advertisement, both classes are updated and have enties for the new advertisement.

I need help understanding the flow, There does not seem to be any documentation for the SMS_AdvertisementInfo class, and everyone just references adding instances to the SMS_Advertisement Class.

What am I doing wrong?  The below code build the new advertisement from and existing one.

```
# Get all the advertisements for the specific package
$adv = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\$SMSSite" -Query "Select * from SMS_Advertisement WHERE PackageID = '$($pkg.PackageID)'" -ComputerName $SMSServer

# Get SMS Parts for creating the new Advertisement: CollectionID, PackageID, Program
$collectionID = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\$SMSSite" -ComputerName $SMSServer -Query "Select * from SMS_Collection WHERE Name = '$AdvCollectionName'").CollectionID
$packageID = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\$SMSSite" -ComputerName $SMSServer -Query "Select PackageID from SMS_Package WHERE Name = '$PkgName'").PackageID
$prg = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\$SMSSite" -ComputerName $SMSServer -Query "Select * from SMS_Program WHERE PackageID = '$($_.packageID)'"


$adv[2] | ForEach-Object {

    # Build hashtable of arguments for the creation
    $arguments =  @{
        AdvertFlags = $_.AdvertFlags;
        AdvertisementName = "WIN7x64TEST - $($_.AdvertisementName)";
        CollectionID = $collectionID;
        PackageID = $_.packageID;
        DeviceFlags = $_.DeviceFlags;
        ProgramName = "WIN7x64TEST - $($_.ProgramName)";
        RemoteClientFlags = $_.RemoteClientFlags;
        SourceSite = $_.SourceSite;
        TimeFlags = $_.TimeFlags
    }

}

# Create the advertisement using the SMS_Advertisement WMI Class
Set-WmiInstance -class SMS_Advertisement -arguments $arguments -namespace "root\SMS\$SMSSite" -ComputerName $SMSServer
```